# Particle with non zero acceleration with zero velocity at that instant - example

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Is it even possible for a particle to have those properties?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange, i would suggest you attempt to improve the questionelse it may be removed for "low quality"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is!

Just imagine throwing a ball upwards with vertical velocity u.

The acceleration of the ball is -10 m/s^2 at any point of the journey ( -10 because it's oppositely directed to the velocity )

The velocity at any point = u -10t

Set this velocity equal to 0, and we get t=u/10.

Thus, u/10 seconds after throwing the ball, the ball will be at instantaneous rest, but the acceleration will be -10 m/s^2.

A qualitative way to look at it is this :

If you throw a ball upwards, you know that it will eventually come down from common sense. If it has a positive velocity at some point, and a negative velocity at some point, there must have been a point where this velocity was zero. And you know that the gravitational acceleration is a constant, thus your conditions are satisfied.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RVRg.png